# Jobscheduler still running when device asleep or screen off?

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I'm building an Android (Oreo) application, in my project i using Jobscheduler for some task in order to these tasks can start on time but when i lock screen or let device asleep so these task can't start, what's wrong ? Why should i do to get these start running on time when screen of or device sleep ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710298/android-scheduling-long-background-task-when-system-is-idle

Comment: Thank you for your help ! I tried use foreground service but sometimes the task still not start, when i lock screen device more than 15 minutes, the task still not start unless press power off to unlock screen device